# Google map marker auto update

Tags: javascript, maps

I have a requirement in javascript, where I'm able to display a google map with multiple cars (all appearing in one direction) appearing in their current lat/lng, after a minute or so the cars might change its lat/lng co ordinates that needs to be updated automatically on screen's google map without having to refresh the page. Also the car appearance might change either to car moving to west or east or south or north.

I'm looking for similar uber drivers map.

My progress is I'm able to read all cars lat/lng from database, create markers on map then display the map. Challenge is updating lat/lng of cars when they change, that must update their lat/lng on map as well.

For example Car A is appearing at co-ordinate 22.322/-83.3223 after 15 seconds Car A moved 100 meters now it has new co-ordinate that must reflect on map.

Any feedback is appreciated.

I don't know what to try.

Comment: So, since you have the new co-ordinates, simply update the marker position with the new co-ordinates. On the other hand, if you don't have the new co-ordinates, first you'll have to find a way to get the new co-ordinates, using AJAX or maybe even `EventSource` and server sent events